# Function template instantiation failing

Tags: c++, function, templates, instantiation

I've been trying to force instantiate the following:

```
//A.h
namespace A {
    template <typename T>
    bool foo (B::C<T>, D);
} 

template bool A::foo<int> (B::C<int>, D);

//1.cpp 

namespace A {
template <typename T> 
bool foo (B::C<T>, D) {
    return false;
}
}




// 2.cpp
#include "A.h"

using namespace A;

void foo()
{///
    ...
    B::C<int> Alpha;
    foo(Alpha, Beta);
}
```

The error messages I am getting are:

> C2785: different return types
>
> C4667: no function template defined that matches forced instantiation

Is there something strikingly wrong with this instantiation, because the error messages don't seem relevant.

Comment: First of all template functions need to be defined in one file.

Comment: Your code is incomplete - the "different return types" error suggests there may be a problem in the "B::C" template class.

Comment: I assumed that the erroneous part of the code is in the actual instantiation. However you are probably right, that the error is not in this piece of code, because I recreated and successfully compiled a similar example.

Answer (score -2):

This happens because templates are expanded at compile time, so the compiler has to know both the definition and the implementation of the templated function, so you can't define the function in one file and implement it in another

Comment: In this case there is a forced instantiation of the template function so it should actually work.

Comment: You can't force the instantiation without seeing the function definition. Perhaps there are several problems here?

Comment: @BoPersson - the code as given in the original question is definitely incomplete - B::C is not defined anywhere, and 1.cpp doesn't include A.h so that cannot compile either.